# App Inventor, display image in Camera mode and start camera with the app?

Tags: android, camera, app-inventor

I have begun to play a little bit with App Inventor 2 (to create a simple android app). However, after a lot of Googling, I can not find two things that I would like to do.

1. When the app starts, I want the camera to be started/opened immediately. I've found how to start the camera from a button in the app but not immediately when you start the app.
2. Add a picture in camera mode. When the camera is running, I want to display a small image in the camera. The image should not be displayed when you have taken a picture but in the camera, before you take the picture. As an example, some cameras have the option to display a GRID when you take a picture.

Answer (score 0):

To start the camera immediately, put the `Camera.TakePicture` method inside the `Screen.Initialize` event

Unfortunately it is not possible to display a small image in the camera preview window, however you could add an image later after taking the app, see the [image extension](https://puravidaapps.com/image.php) and its `Overlay` method.